# Animated Meter Not Being Updated Properly

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I created this animated meter where the green fill and white digits transition to a newly entered value in a number field. Sometimes it works fine, but most of the time the meter digits will only be close to the field value or not change at all. For instance, the digits will match if you enter 400,000 but stop at 442,500 if you enter 450,000.

[image: broken meter]

The problem exists in `updateGauge()` since it gets the fill’s width in any part of the transition. I messed around with it for some time but no luck. Help would be appreciated!

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jkantner/pen/yKbgKe)

```js
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", app);

function app() {
 let inputVal = document.getElementById("val"),
  gaugeVal = document.querySelector(".gauge-value"),
  gauge = document.querySelector(".gauge-inner"),
  gaugeFill = document.querySelector(".gauge-fill"),
  
  updateGauge = function() {
   let rawDigits = (gaugeFill.offsetWidth / gauge.offsetWidth) * inputVal.max,
    roundedDigits = Math.round(rawDigits),
    digits = String(roundedDigits).split("").reverse(),
    displayValueArr = [],
    displayValue = "";

   // use reversed digits to make comma insertion easier
   for (let d in digits) {
    displayValueArr.unshift(digits[d]);
    if (d % 3 == 2 && d < digits.length - 1) {
     displayValueArr.unshift(",");
    }
   }
   for (let a in displayValueArr) {
    displayValue += displayValueArr[a];
   }

   gaugeVal.innerHTML = displayValue;
   
   // update until value reached
   if (rawDigits != inputVal.value) {
    requestAnimFrame(updateGauge);
   }
  },
  updateVal = function() {
   // keep input in range
   if (+inputVal.value > inputVal.max) {
    inputVal.value = inputVal.max;
    
   } else if (+inputVal.value < inputVal.min) {
    inputVal.value = inputVal.min;
   }
   
   gaugeFill.style.width = (inputVal.value/inputVal.max * 100) + "%";
   updateGauge();
  },
  userEvent = "oninput" in document.documentElement ? "input": "change";
 
 inputVal.addEventListener(userEvent,updateVal);
}
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,700";

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
:root {
 font-size: 20px;
}
body, input {
 background: #aca;
 font: 1em "Hind", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
input {
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #aaa inset;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 padding: 0.375em;
}
label {
 display: block;
}
main {
 padding: 3em 1.5em;
}
form, .gauge {
 margin: auto;
}
form {
 text-align: center;
}
.gauge {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 0.75em;
 outline: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 10em;
 height: 1.5em;
 transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.gauge:hover {
 filter: brightness(1.1);
 -webkit-filter: brightness(1.1);
}
.gauge:active {
 filter: brightness(1.25);
 -webkit-filter: brightness(1.25);
 transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
}
.gauge:not(:active):focus > .gauge-details {
 visibility: visible;
}
.gauge > *, .gauge-inner:before, .gauge-details:before {
 position: absolute;
}
/* Statistical */
.gauge-stats {
 top: 0;
 transform: translateY(-25%);
 padding: 0 0.375em;
 z-index: 1;
}
.gauge-symbol, .gauge-value {
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0 #000;
}
.gauge-symbol {
 color: #4c4;
 font-size: 2em;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
.gauge-value {
 color: #fff;
}
/* Fill */
.gauge-inner, .gauge-fill {
 height: 100%;
}
.gauge-inner {
 border: 0.075em solid black;
 border-radius: 0.375em;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.gauge-inner:before {
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 0.375em;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 opacity: 0.5;
 top: 0.125em;
 left: 0.125em;
 width: calc(100% - 0.25em);
 height: 0.5em;
}
.gauge-fill {
 background: linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(255,255,255,0) 0.2em) #080;
 transition: width 1s linear;
 width: 50%;
}
/* Popover */
.gauge-details {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 border-radius: 0.25em;
 color: #fff;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 padding: 0.375em 0.75em;
 text-align: right;
 text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0 #000;
 top: calc(100% + 0.75em);
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.gauge-details:before {
 border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 0.5em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: calc(50% - 0.5em);
}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="gauge" tabindex="0">
  <div class="gauge-stats">
   <span class="gauge-symbol">$</span>
   <span class="gauge-value">500,000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="gauge-inner">
   <div class="gauge-fill"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gauge-details">Max: <strong>1,000,000</strong></div>
 </div>
 <form>
  <label for="val">Change value to:</label>
  <input id="val" type="number" min="0" step="1" max="1000000" value="500000">
 </form>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is connected to this ratio :

```
(gaugeFill.offsetWidth / gauge.offsetWidth)
```

offsetWidth return the width of the element **including its border**.
So you can get rid of your problem by removing the border of the class gauge-inner.
If your not too attached to your round border, you can replace it by a simple straight outline.
Otherwise, you can create something that looks like a border using box-shadow.

Also, since in your case gaugeFill.offsetWidth is an integer that can only be inferior or equal to 400, roundedDigits have only 400 possible values, so it's not very accurate. **That's why you should replace the displayed number by inputVal.value.** (I didn't do it myself for that you can see that the gauge is repaired.)

```js
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
   window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", app);

function app() {
 let inputVal = document.getElementById("val"),
  gaugeVal = document.querySelector(".gauge-value"),
  gauge = document.querySelector(".gauge-inner"),
  gaugeFill = document.querySelector(".gauge-fill"),
  
        // Added variables
        oldInputValue = 500000,
        timeDifference = 0,
        valueDifference = 0,
        timeBetweenUpdating = 100; // (in milliseconds) The digits will be updated every 0.1s
        
  updateGauge = function() {
            
   /*let rawDigits = ((gaugeFill.offsetWidth) / (gauge.offsetWidth)) * inputVal.max,
    roundedDigits = Math.round(rawDigits),*/
            
            // the value of the digits when they change rapidly
            var changingDigits = oldInputValue;
            // the time left to animate digits
            var timeLeft = Math.abs(timeDifference);
            
            oldInputValue = Number(inputVal.value);
            
            // Every 0.1s the digits a recalculated and displayed.        
            var digitsUpdating = setInterval(function () {
                changingDigits += (timeBetweenUpdating/timeDifference)*valueDifference;

                timeLeft -=timeBetweenUpdating;

                // If there is no time left (the animation is over)
                // the updating stops and the last value to be displayed is inputVal.value
                if (timeLeft < 0)
                {
                    changingDigits = inputVal.value;
                    clearInterval(digitsUpdating);
                }

                digits = String(Math.trunc(changingDigits)).split("").reverse(),
                displayValueArr = [],
                displayValue = "";

                // use reversed digits to make comma insertion easier
                for (let d in digits) {
                    displayValueArr.unshift(digits[d]);
                    if (d % 3 == 2 && d < digits.length - 1) {
                        displayValueArr.unshift(",");
                    }
                }
                for (let a in displayValueArr) {
                    displayValue += displayValueArr[a];
                }

                gaugeVal.innerHTML = displayValue;

            }, timeBetweenUpdating);

   
   // update until value reached
   /*if (rawDigits != inputVal.value) {
    requestAnimFrame(updateGauge);
   }*/
  },
  updateVal = function() {
   // keep input in range
   if (+inputVal.value > inputVal.max) {
    inputVal.value = inputVal.max;
    
   } else if (+inputVal.value < inputVal.min) {
    inputVal.value = inputVal.min;
   }
            
            // Added code; animate the gauge fill.
            valueDifference = inputVal.value - oldInputValue;
            var width = String((inputVal.value/ inputVal.max) * 100) + "%";
            timeDifference = (Math.abs(valueDifference) / inputVal.max) * 1500; // Fill the gauge entirely would take 1500ms.
            jQuery(gaugeFill).animate({width: width}, timeDifference);

   /*gaugeFill.style.width = (inputVal.value/inputVal.max * 100) + "%";*/
   updateGauge();
  },
  userEvent = "oninput" in document.documentElement ? "input": "change";

 inputVal.addEventListener(userEvent,updateVal);
}
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:400,700";

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
:root {
 font-size: 20px;
}
body, input {
 background: #aca;
 font: 1em "Hind", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
input {
 background: #fff;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #aaa inset;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 padding: 0.375em;
}
label {
 display: block;
}
main {
 padding: 3em 1.5em;
}
form, .gauge {
 margin: auto;
}
form {
 text-align: center;
}
.gauge {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 0.75em;
 outline: 0;
 position: relative;
 width: 10em;
 height: 1.5em;
 /*transition: all 0.1s linear;*/
}
.gauge:hover {
 filter: brightness(1.1);
 -webkit-filter: brightness(1.1);
}
.gauge:active {
 filter: brightness(1.25);
 -webkit-filter: brightness(1.25);
 transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
}
.gauge:not(:active):focus > .gauge-details {
 visibility: visible;
}
.gauge > *, .gauge-inner:before, .gauge-details:before {
 position: absolute;
}
/* Statistical */
.gauge-stats {
 top: 0;
 transform: translateY(-25%);
 padding: 0 0.375em;
 z-index: 1;
}
.gauge-symbol, .gauge-value {
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #000;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0 #000;
}
.gauge-symbol {
 color: #4c4;
 font-size: 2em;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
.gauge-value {
 color: #fff;
}
/* Fill */
.gauge-inner, .gauge-fill {
 height: 100%;
}
.gauge-inner {
 border: 0.075em solid black;
 border-radius: 0.375em;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.gauge-inner:before {
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 0.375em;
 content: "";
 display: block;
 opacity: 0.5;
 top: 0.125em;
 left: 0.125em;
 width: calc(100% - 0.25em);
 height: 0.5em;
}
.gauge-fill {
 background: linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.7),rgba(255,255,255,0) 0.2em) #080;
 /*transition: width 1s linear;*/
 width: 50%;
}
/* Popover */
.gauge-details {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 border-radius: 0.25em;
 color: #fff;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 padding: 0.375em 0.75em;
 text-align: right;
 text-shadow: 0 0.1em 0 #000;
 top: calc(100% + 0.75em);
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.gauge-details:before {
 border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 0.5em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: calc(50% - 0.5em);
}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="gauge" tabindex="0">
  <div class="gauge-stats">
   <span class="gauge-symbol">$</span>
   <span class="gauge-value">500,000</span>
  </div>
  
  

  <div class="gauge-inner">
   <div class="gauge-fill"></div>
  </div>

  
 
  
  <div class="gauge-details">Max: <strong>1,000,000</strong></div>
 </div>
 <form>
  <label for="val">Change value to:</label>
  <input id="val" type="number" min="0" step="1" max="1000000" value="500000">
 </form>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</main>
```

**Second edit :**

As I said before, I used jquery for its `animate()` function. So I added the jQuery file in the HTML (at the end). I also removed the `transition` properties in the CSS.
Since I'm not using `gaugeFill.offsetWidth` anymore, I restablished the borders.

I comment the changes I've done directly in the javascript file.

The animation seems to finally work perfectly. The gauge fill and the numbers are animated and the borders restablished.

I must tell that was a lot harder than I first thought...

Comment: Changing the border to a box shadow may have slightly improved accuracy, but if you change the value by 1, 10, or 100, the gauge still won’t budge. I tried using `inputVal.value` instead of `(gaugeFill.offsetWidth / gauge.offsetWidth) * inputVal.max` for `rawDigits`, but there was no digit animation.

Comment: @Jon Kantner Ok, I edit my answer to propose another solution.

Comment: I added something to `updateVal` like the additional code you provided, but it didn’t seem to help; the meter just behaved more erratically. To get what I’m looking for, I guess I’ll have write something different instead.

Comment: @JonKantner I edited my post again. Now it should work !  :)   I change the snippet so you can try. You'll find all the modifications I had to do at the bottom of my post ("Second edit"). Don't hesitate to tell me if something is still bothering you.

Comment: I guess that will do. I can adjust anything myself if needed. Thanks!